# Icons as "type of category" as form input not updating the UI to show user selection

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to add this in my form.

[image]

Which is adding medications, I have four types of medication: syringe, bottle, pill, or tablet. So far, I have done the row of icons wrapped with GestureDetector to see if a user picked one type, my inputVariable is being update however, the ui is not changing.. I'm unsure as to what the problem is.. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Here is my code:

```
// Code in Form
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MedicineTypeColumn(
                          type: MedicineType.Bottle,
                          name: "Bottle",
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.prescriptionBottle,
                          isSelected: a == MedicineType.Bottle ? true : false),
                      MedicineTypeColumn(
                          type: MedicineType.Pill,
                          name: "Pill",
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.capsules,
                          isSelected: a == MedicineType.Pill ? true : false),
                      MedicineTypeColumn(
                          type: MedicineType.Syringe,
                          name: "Syringe",
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.syringe,
                          isSelected: a == MedicineType.Syringe ? true : false),
                      MedicineTypeColumn(
                          type: MedicineType.Tablet,
                          name: "Tablet",
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.ban,
                          isSelected: a == MedicineType.Tablet ? true : false),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

// New Widget for MedicineTypes
class MedicineTypeColumn extends StatefulWidget {
  final MedicineType type;
  final String name;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool isSelected;

  MedicineTypeColumn(
      {Key key,
      @required this.type,
      @required this.name,
      @required this.icon,
      @required this.isSelected})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MedicineTypeColumnState createState() => _MedicineTypeColumnState();
}

class _MedicineTypeColumnState extends State<MedicineTypeColumn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Medicine> medTemp = Medicine.medList;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          medTemp[0].medicineType = widget.type.toString();

          print(medTemp[0].medicineType);
          print(medTemp[0].medicineType.runtimeType);
        });
      },
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 85,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                child: Icon(
                  widget.icon,
                  size: 45,
                  color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF3EB16F),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 80,
              height: 30,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color:
                    widget.isSelected ? Color(0xFF3EB16F) : Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF3EB16F),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Logs to show that the inputVariable is being updated.

```
I/flutter ( 4614): MedicineType.Pill
I/flutter ( 4614): String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GestureDetector should be outside the MedicineTypeColumn. You can make MedicineTypeColumn stateless widget and manage the state in the other widget where you have the form. On each item of the row add the gesture detector:

```
// Code in Form
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      a = MedicineType.Bottle;
    });
  },
  child: MedicineTypeColumn(
    type: MedicineType.Bottle,
    name: "Bottle",
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.prescriptionBottle,
    isSelected: a == MedicineType.Bottle,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that lead me to the correct answer. The isSelected property of the widget should be: `a == MedicineType.Tablet.toString() ? true : false` since I was setting a to be a String.